Azure Role Assignment in Resource group does not pass down to the service level
After i created Key Vault in Azure, i can not add secret value, and there is warn saying "The operation is not allowed by RBAC. If role assignments were recently changed, please wait several minutes for role assignments to become effective.".
I think the error is saying my user does not have correct role permission. So i went to the Azure Subscription level, click the Access Control(IAM) tab on the left hand side panel, assign the user with Key Vault Admin role, try add secret again with same error. Then i went to the Resource group level, click the Access Control(IAM) tab on the left hand side panel, assign the user with Key Vault Admin role, still getting the same error.
Then i went to the key vault page, click Access Control(IAM) tab on the left hand side panel, assign the user with key vault admin role, now i can correctly add secret value.
So my question is, since my key vault is within this resource group and within this subscription, why when i create and assign user role in the up level, the role permission does not pass down to the individual service level.

Hi @Jason596 Any update?


why when i create and assign user role in the up level, the role permission does not pass down to the individual service level.

The role permission will pass down or inherits to individual service level from higher scopes but takes some time to reflect the changes.
Initially, I created one key vault and got same error while adding new secret without proper RBAC roles:

To resolve the error, you can assign Key Vault Administrator role to signed-in user at any scope like subscription, resource group or key vault level. But there will be delay in taking effect based on selected scope.
In my case, I assigned Key Vault Administrator role to signed-in user at subscription level:

When I tried to create secret now, it worked but need to wait few minutes and refresh the page to reflect the change:

In your case, assigning role at key vault level worked as it takes less time to reflect the change compared to other scopes (subscription, resource group).
Reference:
 Azure Key Vault role-based access control | Microsoft Learn
